# Populating dynamic table row with dynamic select

Tags: javascript

I created a dynamic table using Javascript. I want to `appendChild` the cell of each row with a select.

First I tried it using it in a different `populateTableCell` function after the creation of table is finished. I thought it is better for code readability. But I couldn't succeed.

That's why I tried to populate it in the same function. However, it only populates the very last row.

```
<table id="informationTable">
    <tr>
        <th>userID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Profile</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the JS I tried...

```
    function setAllUsers(users){
        //Create array of options to be added
        var array = ["Normal","Incident","Major Incident"];

        //Create select list
        var selectList = document.createElement("select");

        //Create and append the options
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.value = array[i];
            option.text = array[i];
            selectList.appendChild(option);
        }

        for(i = 0; i < users.length-1; i++){
            var table = document.getElementById('informationTable');
            var row = document.createElement("tr");
            row.id = users[i];  

            var cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);

            cell0.innerHTML = users[i];
            cell0.value = users[i];

            cell1.id=users[i]+"-status";
            cell1.class="statusClass";

            cell2.id=users[i]+"-profile";
            cell2.class="profileClass";

            cell2.appendChild(selectList);

            table.appendChild(row);
        }
    }
```

I also tried putting the `createElement('select')`, `createElement('option')` and `select.appendChild(option)` inside the "for" loop. But this time page never loads.
I found a similar post and tried to use it.

[How to dynamically insert a table row with a select box with options in a table using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620367/how-to-dynamically-insert-a-table-row-with-a-select-box-with-options-in-a-table)

But here each rows are appending due to button click.

Thanks for your answers.
Sincerely,
Alp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- It probably makes more sense to add a new column instead of appending into the profile cell, so you should add a new column header and run `insertCell` one more time
- You should be using `className`, not `class` - `class` is a reserved word in Javascript.
- Unless your users array contains HTML, you should use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` for performance reasons.
- You need to run `selectList.cloneNode(true)` when you append to the cell so that you get a new copy of the element each time.
- It is expensive and pointless to run `var table = document.getElementById('informationTable');` on each iteration of your loop, you only need to get that handle one time during your function's lifecycle - so move that to the top and outside your loop

I don't have your `users` array, but here is a working example with a guess on what your array might look like (feel free to replace `let` and `const` with `var` if you need to):

```js
const users = [
  ['1', 'Active', 'Bob'],
  ['2', 'Disabled', 'Alice']
];

function setAllUsers(users){
    //Create array of options to be added
    const priorities = ["Normal","Incident","Major Incident"];
 const table = document.getElementById('informationTable');
    //Create select list
    const selectList = document.createElement("select");

    //Create and append the options
    for (let i = 0; i < priorities.length; i++) {
        const option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = priorities[i];
        option.text = priorities[i];
        selectList.appendChild(option);
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
        const row = document.createElement("tr");
        row.id = 'user-'+users[i][0];
        
        const cell0 = row.insertCell(0);
        const cell1 = row.insertCell(1);
        const cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
        const cell3 = row.insertCell(3);

        cell0.textContent = users[i][0];

        cell1.id = users[i][1]+"-status";
        cell1.className = "statusClass";
  cell1.textContent = users[i][1];
        
        cell2.id=users[i][2]+"-profile";
        cell2.className = "profileClass";
  cell2.textContent = users[i][2];

        cell3.appendChild(selectList.cloneNode(true));

        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}

setAllUsers(users)
```

```html
<table id="informationTable">
    <tr>
        <th>userID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Profile</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, Rob. I applied all your valuable suggestions. It works as it should be.